# How to group multiple hashes with same key into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Starting form an array of hashes:

```
roles =[
 {:id=>1, :name=>"alpha", :gid=>1}, 
 {:id=>2, :name=>"beta", :gid=>2},   
 {:id=>3, :name=>"delta", :gid=>1}, 
 {:id=>4, :name=>"epsilon", :gid=>1}, 
 {:id=>5, :name=>"zeta", :gid=>3}
]
```

I am trying to get another structure:

```
groups = [
 {:gid=>1, :roles=>[
    {:id=>1, :name=>"alpha"}, 
    {:id=>3, :name=>"delta"}, 
    {:id=>4, :name=>"epsilon"}]}, 
 {:gid=>2, :roles=>[{:id=>2, :name=>"beta"}]}, 
 {:gid=>3, :roles=>[{:id=>5, :name=>"zeta"}]}
]
```

ANSWERS -- all answers output the same .. however I have to vote for the fastest one ..

```
time1 = Benchmark.measure do
 (1..10000).each do 
   roles.group_by { |e| e.slice(:gid) }.map{
     |k,v| k.merge(:roles => v.map { |e| e.except(:gid)}) }
 end
end
puts time1
user       system      total        real
1.150000   0.010000   1.160000 (  1.165781)

time2 = Benchmark.measure do
  (1..10000).each do
   roles.group_by{|el| el[:gid]}.map{|gid, els|
   {gid: gid, roles: els.map{ |el| { id: el[:id], name: el[:name]}}}}
   end
end
puts time2
user       system      total        real
0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.278286)

time3 = Benchmark.measure do
  (1..10000).each do
 roles.group_by{|h| h.delete(:gid)}.map{|k, v| {gid: k, roles: v}}
  end
end
puts time3
user       system      total        real
0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.134478)
```

Comment: updated with the correct given output ...

Comment: the updated expected structure is the one output from the correct answer ... simple , I don't see what's incorrect

Comment: ok I removed the intermediate result which doesn't add any useful information for further readers and just kept input and expected output + performances

Comment: Writing code to minimize CPU time is like buying a car for its zero to sixty clocking. There may be other things to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer to your question is:

```
gid = nil
h = [
  {:id=>1, :name=>"alpha", :gid=>1},
  {:id=>3, :name=>"delta", :gid=>1},
  {:id=>4, :name=>"epsilon", :gid=>1}
]
.each{|h| gid = h.delete(:gid)}
{gid: gid, roles: h}
```

but the whole thing can be done like this:

```
roles.group_by{|h| h.delete(:gid)}.map{|k, v| {gid: k, roles: v}}
```

Comment: Your answer is the faster

Answer (score 0):

```
roles = [
  {:id => 1, :name=>"alpha", :gid=>1}, 
  {:id => 2, :name=>"beta", :gid=>2}, 
  {:id => 3, :name=>"delta", :gid=>1}, 
  {:id => 4, :name=>"epsilon", :gid=>1},
  {:id => 5, :name=>"zeta", :gid=>3}
]

roles.group_by do |el|
  el[:gid]
end.map do |gid, els|
  { 
    gid: gid, 
    roles: els.map{ |el| { id: el[:id], name: el[:name] } } 
  }
end
```

Comment: both answers give the correct output, however I have to vote for the fastest 
 0.278286

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Ruby 1.8.7 with ActiveSupport for methods `slice()` and `except()`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'    

roles.group_by { |e| e.slice(:gid) }.
      map      { |k,v| k.merge(:roles => v.map { |e| e.except(:gid)}) }

#=> [{:gid=>1, :roles=>[{:name=>"alpha", :id=>1},
#                       {:name=>"delta", :id=>3},
#                       {:name=>"epsilon", :id=>4}]},
#    {:gid=>2, :roles=>[{:name=>"beta", :id=>2}]},
#    {:gid=>3, :roles=>[{:name=>"zeta", :id=>5}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks
both answers give the correct output, however I have to vote for the fastest 

 1.165781

Answer (score 0):

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here that block is:

```
{ |k,ov,nv| { :gid=>ov[:gid], :roles=>ov[:roles]+nv[:roles] } }
```

where `k` is the common key, `ov` is the value of the key in the being constructed and `nv` is the value of the hash being merged in.

The calculation:

```
roles.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:gid]=>{ :gid=>g[:gid],
                      :roles=>[{:id=>g[:id], :name=>g[:name]}]
                    }
          ) { |k,ov,nv| { :gid=>ov[:gid], :roles=>ov[:roles]+nv[:roles] } }
end.values
  #=> [{:gid=>1, :roles=>[{:id=>1, :name=>"alpha"},
  #                       {:id=>3, :name=>"delta"},
  #                       {:id=>4, :name=>"epsilon"}]},
  #    {:gid=>2, :roles=>[{:id=>2, :name=>"beta"}]},
  #    {:gid=>3, :roles=>[{:id=>5, :name=>"zeta"}]}]
```